# Use facebook auth on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, https, passport-facebook

I have a node js aplication with passport.js facebook auth. Facebook auth on local works but when i try on keroku i get:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app >from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Do i need to pay samethink to heroku to use https. When i use local auth seems to use https. (https://xxx.herokuapp.com/localauth it's work)

Comment: Did you try to add the heroku address on facebook sdk config to accepted Redirect URI? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self) you can set up non-production apps with a self-signed certificate for  for free. After searching at Google I also found [this guide](https://medium.com/@franxyzxyz/setting-up-free-https-with-heroku-ssl-and-lets-encrypt-80cf6eac108e) for setting up Heroku in combination with Let's Encrypt

Comment: @StephanSchrjiver it think is free only if you have hobby plan on heroku which cost 7$/month..

Comment: @LucasCosta yes i do this